# why my reverse is not working on full linked list and it is working on half of the linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, reverse

I tried solving palindrome of linked list in leetcode, initially i thought of just reversing the linked list and compare the original with reverse to find palindrome, but the reverse function is not working. after seeing the solutions, I found 2 pointer method, and solved it now my reverse is working.(commented are the 2 pointer).

Any help, why the full reverse is not and it is working for half linked list.
Thanks in advance.

`enter code here`

```
       class Solution {
         public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
          ListNode fast=head;
          ListNode slow=reverse(head);
          // while(fast!=null && fast.next!=null){
          //     fast=fast.next.next;
          //     slow=slow.next;
          // }
          // slow=reverse(slow);
          // fast=head;
          while(slow!=null){
             if(fast.val!=slow.val){
             return false;
          }
           fast=fast.next;
            slow=slow.next;
        }
       return true;
      }
     public ListNode reverse(ListNode head){
        ListNode prev=null;
        ListNode cur=head;
        ListNode ne=head.next;
        while(cur!=null){
         cur.next=prev;
         prev=cur;
         cur=ne;
         if(ne!=null){
            ne=ne.next;
         }
      }
       return prev;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The "full" reverse version cannot work, because the reversal is done *inplace*, which means that the *original* list is reversed, and specifically all `next` pointers have been altered. You write *"...and compare the original with..."*, but there is no original anymore. It has been reversed.

That means that after having called `reverse(head)`, the node at `head` is now the tail of this list. It is still the same node, but its `next` pointer is now `null`. And since `fast` references the same node as `head`, the loop will end after its first iteration... `fast=fast.next` will surely make `fast` null.

When only the second half of the list is reversed, the first half is still as it was originally, and so the `head` node still has its `next` pointer going forward, and a forward walk is possible until the half of the nodes have been traversed.

It may help to visualise it. Let's say we have this list:

```
       head
        ↓
      ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐
      │ data: 1 │   │ data: 2 │   │ data: 3 │   │ data: 4 │
      │ next: ────► │ next: ────► │ next: ────► │ next: ────►null
      └─────────┘   └─────────┘   └─────────┘   └─────────┘
```

After code has executed to reverse the *whole* list, we get:

```
       head fast                                 slow
        ↓    ↓                                    ↓
      ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐
      │ data: 1 │   │ data: 2 │   │ data: 3 │   │ data: 4 │
null◄──── :next │ ◄──── :next │ ◄──── :next │ ◄──── :next │
      └─────────┘   └─────────┘   └─────────┘   └─────────┘
```

Note how there is no way anymore to go from the leftmost node to its right neighbor.

Now see what happens when the code executes that performs the half-reversal. First it moves the `slow` pointer into place with a loop:

```
       head                        slow
        ↓                           ↓ 
      ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐
      │ data: 1 │   │ data: 2 │   │ data: 3 │   │ data: 4 │
      │ next: ────► │ next: ────► │ next: ────► │ next: ────►null
      └─────────┘   └─────────┘   └─────────┘   └─────────┘
```

...then it calls `reverse(slow)`:

```
       head fast                                 slow
        ↓    ↓                                    ↓ 
      ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐
      │ data: 1 │   │ data: 2 │   │ data: 3 │   │ data: 4 │
      │ next: ────► │ next: ────► │┌─ :next │ ◄──── :next │
      └─────────┘   └─────────┘   └│────────┘   └─────────┘
                             null◄─┘
```

Now both `slow` and `fast` can move in the intended direction. If they follow the `next` pointers then they can move "toward" each other. If the list happens to be a palindrome, that loop will continue until `slow` is null, which is when both pointers have traversed half of the list.

The full reversal algorithm would have worked if `reverse` would have created *new* nodes and linked those together into a new, reversed list, leaving the original untouched.

Comment: And why the reverse (slow) is working as I am applying same function to it.

Comment: I added a visualisation to my answer. I hope that clarifies it.